# why can't @apply imported style mixin without <custom-style></custom-style>

Tags: polymer-3.x

Why if i want to @apply the imported mixin, custom-style tag it's needed?

```
import '@polymer/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout.js';

import {html} from '@polymer/polymer/lib/utils/html-tag.js';

           const template = html`
                <custom-style>
                    <style>
                        body{
                            @apply --layout-vertical;
                            @apply --layout-center;
                        }
                    </style> 
                </custom-style>
            `;
```

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers have not implemented the Shadow DOM v1 specifications. To make sure your apps and elements display correctly in these browsers, you'll need to use custom-style to ensure that styling information doesn't "leak" into the local DOM of your elements.

> custom-style enables a set of polyfills that ensure that styles in your apps and elements behave as you would expect from the Shadow DOM v1 specifications, even in browsers that don't implement these specifications.
>
> To ensure that your styles behave according to the Shadow DOM v1 specifications in all browsers, use custom-style when you define document-level styles

for more [information](https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/devguide/style-shadow-dom#custom-style):

Comment: "to ensure that styling information doesn't 'leak' into the local DOM".

That's the point i'm not understanding, it's more like browser can't see the imported mixin from the "<style>" (it say unknown property) until it has been wrapped inside "custom-style". It's like "<custom-style>" is also expanding the "style scope".